# MATLAB: Create a high resolution PDF images

Tags: matlab, pdf

I am trying to convert a high resolution image (30in width x 60in height) to a pdf file in MATLAB. I tried print, exportgraphics, and couple scripts online but I keep getting low quality output. I also tried setting the resolution to 300dpi but it didnt work. Please if you have any suggestions, share with me and I will test. Many thanks!

Image file used (renamed to map.png): `https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/de/Political_map_of_the_World_%28January_2015%29.svg/9444px-Political_map_of_the_World_%28January_2015%29.svg.png`

MATLAB commands used:

```
world=imread('map.png');
imshow(world)
exportgraphics(gcf,'world.pdf','ContentType','vector','Resolution',300)
#Texts in picture is blurry
print -dpdf 'world.pdf'
#Texts in picture is still blurry
exportfig(gcf, 'world.pdf', 'format','pdf','Resolution', 300,'Renderer', 'painters');
#this is a script from the MATLAB file exchange. Texts still blurry
```

Comment: You're going to need a [mcve] here, and it's much more helpful to us if you _show us_ what you've tried, "I've tried `print`" does not give us any information about what you actually ran; there are numerous settings available in that function and impossible to know which you used. You should be able to save to pdf as vector graphics, where resolution is a non-issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I edited my question and added more info. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it by importing pdfbox (java) and importing the image as a bufferedimage then creating a document with pdmodel.PDDocument then adding a page with a custom size using the bufferedimage.getWidth and same for length then I streamed the bufferedimage to the page and saved the document to a pdf file. The code is on my work PC if anyone is interested I will copy it here.

Comment: "...I will copy it here" Only the most relevant snippet. If this code is proprietary to a company, do be careful with anything that might be confidential.